# How to Rotate Unity UI RectTransform so that it points at another UI Element

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

How would I aim rotate a Unity UI Element's RectTransform so that the Element points at another UI Element on a World Space Canvas?

In the image below there's a Slider (But it could be any UI Element) that I would like to rotate so that it always faces the Button as I drag the Button around the Canvas.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25jAB.png)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

Place a script on the element you want to rotate that contains something like this:

```
//References for the pivot position of the UI elements
public RectTransform targetAnchor;
RectTransform selfAnchor;

//Set the rotating elements RectTransform
void Start() {
  selfAnchor = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

//Update the UI elements rotation
void Update() {
    float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan((targetAnchor.y - selfAnchor.y)/(targetAnchor.x - selfAnchor.x));
    selfAnchor.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0, targetRotation);
}
```

I can't test this at the moment but if you're still having issues I can update it when I get home.

Comment: ArcTan only gives a result that lies between -90 and 90 degrees right? 

Just a heads up as well.  In the above example you'd have to multiply targetRotation by Mathf.Rad2Deg as the Atan Method returns the angle in radians.

Comment: Unless you like division by zero errors when your target and self are at the same X coordinate, it ist strongly recommended to use `Mathf.Atan2` instead of `Mathf.Atan`.